# Naives Bayes Classifier for bag of vectorized sentences

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp, naivebayes

### **Summary : How to train a Naive Bayes Classifier on a bag of vectorized sentences ?**

*Example here :*

```
X_train[0] = [[0, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1]]
y_train[0] = 1

X_train[1] = [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1]]
y_train[1] = 0
```

.

---

### 1) Context of the project : perform sentiment analysis on batch of tweets to perform market prediction

**I am working on a sentiment analysis for stock market classification.**
As I am new to these techniques, I tried to replicate one from this article :
http://cs229.stanford.edu/proj2015/029_report.pdf

But I am facing a big issue with it. Let me explain the main steps of the article I realized :

1. I collected a huge amount of tweets during 4 months (7 million)
2. I cleaned then (removing stop words, hashtags, mentions, punctuation, etc...)
3. I grouped them into period interval of 1 hour
4. I created a target that tell if the price of the Bitcoin has gone down or up after
   one hour (0 = down ; 1 = up)

What I need to do next is to train my Bernoulli Naive Bayes Model with this.
To do this, the article mentions to vectorize the tweets this way.

[image]

[.....]
[image]

What I did with the CountVectorizer class from sklearn.

### 2 ) The issue : the dimension of the inputs doesn't match Naive Bayes standards

But then I encounter an issue when I try to fit the Bernoulli Naive Bayes model, following the article method :

[image]

So, one observation is shaped this way :

- **input shape** (one observation): (nb_tweets_on_this_1hour_interval,  vocabulary_size= 10 000)

```py
    one_observation_input = [
        [0, 1, 0 ....., 0, 0], #Tweet 1 vectorized
        ....,
        [1, 0, ....., 1, 0]    #Tweet N vectorized
    ]#All of the values are 0 or 1
```

- **output shape** (one observation): (1,)

  one_observation_output = [0] #Can only be 0 or 1

When I tried to fit my Sklearn Bernoulli Naive Bayes model with this type of value, I am getting this error

`>>>  ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2.`

Indeed, the model expects binary input shaped this way :

- **input : (nb_features)**

  *ex: [0, 0, 1, 0, ...., 1, 0, 1]*

while I am giving it vectors of binary values !

### 3 ) What I have tried

So far, I tried several things to resolve this :

- Associating the label for every tweet, but the results are not good since the tweets are really noisy
- Flatten the inputs so the shape for one input is (nb_tweets_on_this_1hour_interval*vocabulary_size, ). But the model can not train as the number of tweets every hour is not constant.

### 4 ) Conclusion

I don't know if the error comes from my misunderstanding of the article or of the Nayes Bayes models.

**How to train efficiently a naive bayes classifier on a bag of tweets ?**

Here is my training code :

```py
    bnb = BernoulliNB()

    uniqueY = [0, 1]#I give the algorithm the 2 classes I want to classify the tweets with. This is needed for the partial fit

    for _index, row in train_df.iterrows():#I have to use a for loop to partialy fit my Bernouilli Naive Bayes classifier to prevent from out of memory issues

        #row["Tweet"] contains all the (cleaned) tweets over 1hour interval this way  : ["I like Bitcoin", "Nice portfolio", ...., "I am the last tweet of the interval"]
        X_train = vectorizer.transform(row["Tweet"]).toarray()
        #X_train contrains all of the row["Tweet"] tweets vectorizes with a bag of words algorithm which return this kind of data : [[0, 1, 0 ....., 0, 0], ....,[1, 0, ....., 1, 0]]

        y_train = row["target"]
        #Target is 0 if the market is going down after the tweets and 1 if it is going up

        bnb.partial_fit([X_train], [y_train], uniqueY)
        #Again, I use partial fit to avoid out of memory issues
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a `TfidfVectorizer`.  See: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html

Basically, when we have variable length documents (or a variable number of tweets, in your case) and we are willing to use a bag-of-words representation/assumption, we want to build up a normalized count of the occurrences of words (or more generally N-grams) in each input training example.

Loosely speaking, for the 7 tweets in your two training examples, you would take a union of the terms represented over those seven tweets and that would become your vocabulary.  Then each tweet would be represented by a vector in that vocabulary. Finally, a bag of tweets would be the summation of the individual tweets.  Those counts are then normalized with respect to their occurrence in the total corpus and their occurrence in that particular document-example (TfIdf stands for term-frequency inverse-document-frequency).

From the `scikit-learn` docs link above:

```sh
>>> from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
>>> corpus = [
...     'This is the first document.',
...     'This document is the second document.',
...     'And this is the third one.',
...     'Is this the first document?',
... ]
>>> vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
>>> X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
>>> vectorizer.get_feature_names_out()
array(['and', 'document', 'first', 'is', 'one', 'second', 'the', 'third',
       'this'], ...)
>>> print(X.shape)
(4, 9)
```

In your case, I would simply concatenate across your bag-of-tweets to get the first documents, second document, etc.  The `TfidfVectorizer` uses a sparse representation to reduce its memory footprint.

(After rereading your question and seeing that you are using a `CountVectorizer`, you could simply sum over your tweets, if you wanted to.  But, TF-IDF is a pretty standard technique to use.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! As you said, my tweets are already vectorized. Concatenate is actually a great idea, but I would like to try the way the study does. Indeed, Bernoulli naive bayes is great for short document (a few words/sentences) while concatenate produce huge documents (around 250 000 words per document).
Actually I already tried it, and it didn't work pretty well :/

Comment: ML papers are sadly unclear, from the paper I assume over the total set of tweets the class (+/-) is generated from that hour's Bitcoin delta.  So, their training dataset should have (#tweets rows, #vocab size columns).  You say you tried this under (3), part 1.  Since you have tried the paper's method and it doesn't work for you, I still recommend  summing over tweets-in-an-hour (or some other interval).  Your training data size will be (#hour intervals, #vocab size).  This will be far, far smaller than the paper's dataset and be clearly interpretable.  Also, you should normalize somehow.

Answer (score 0):

The error is basically the `[X_train]` which is increasing the number of dimensions in code.
In your code

```
        bnb.partial_fit([X_train], [y_train], uniqueY)
        #X_train in brackets are causing your error
```

The Bernoulli NB is expecting an array with TWO dimensions only and putting X_train in square is making it three dimensions instead.

If you change your code to this then it should work

```
        bnb.partial_fit(X_train, y_train, uniqueY)
```

An example code for explanation:

```
import numpy as np

from sklearn.naive_bayes import BernoulliNB
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
corpus = [
     'This is the first document.',
     'This document is the second document.',
     'And this is the third one.',
     'Is this the first document?']


result=[1,0,0,1]
result=np.array(result)

vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)

print (vectorizer.get_feature_names())
# OUTPUT: ['and', 'document', 'first', 'is', 'one', 'second', 'the', 'third', 'this']

X_train=X.toarray()
print (X_train.shape)
# output: (4, 9)

print (result.shape)
# output: (4,)



clf = BernoulliNB()

clf.partial_fit(X_train, result,[0,1]) # WORKS FINE 


#clf.partial_fit([X_train], [result], [0,1]) ## ERROR ERROR
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer ! But it doesn't solve my problem, as I am trying to make one prediction every N tweets (not one prediction for one tweet). The difficulty here is that N is not constant.

Comment: you can use X_train.sum(axis=1)  that will add up all N tweets.

Comment: considering that your array shape is (total training examples, N,vocab_size). 
Since N is not constant, you can iterate through each example and sum over N:
`for i in range(0, total_examples): X_train[i].sum(axis=1)`